# ios what is UITextField Border color value

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I have a UIView and I want to set the border color to the UIView.

I have a UITextField and below that I have a UIView. In that View I have some check boxes.

Now I want to give same look and feel as UITextField For that I want following thing

- I need to make the UIView round corder as UITextField (I have done that)
- I need to apply same border color value to UIView as UITextField is having

I am stuck in point number two. I am getting border color of UITextField as below

```
myTextField.layer.borderColor
```

but with that I am getting more black color border, but on UITextField it looks very nice and low color value.

Please help me in finding a real value.

Comment: Have you set a border color to the text field? or you want to get the default one?

Comment: Your border might be looking darker because of different border width from UITextField and your View, along with setting border color same as UITextField set your view's border width as well `self.your_customView.layer.borderWidth = textField.layer.borderWidth`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari its still not working , that Idea came in my mind and it did not work

Answer (score 2):

```
//for normal
textView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

//for RgbColour 

textView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xC12326, alphaVal: 1).cgColor

extension UIColor{
    convenience init(rgb: UInt, alphaVal: CGFloat) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: alphaVal
        )
    }
}
```

Note: - customize your color and give the same border it should look like same.

Comment: Should I change those properties on the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Default control border color is #c2c2c2.

Comment: this has nothing to do with question

Comment: what should be its radius ?

Comment: Default radius value is 0.35px

Comment: though your answer has good color, but now I think you do not have any IOS experience